# Application cache event noupdate is not getting fired intermittently on the Safari browser.

Tags: safari, manifest, html5-appcache, ios12, application-cache

The window.applicationCache status is 2(Checking) when the issue occurs. I have some method called on the listener to some of the application cache change events. But when the issue occurs, I see none of the events getting fired.
Request to Manifest is also stuck forever when I inspect the network tab.
The device I am using is Ipad IOS-12.0.

In the success scenario, the status is 2(checking), then it raises noupdate event and subsequently the application cache status changes to 1(idle). This issue is intermittent and gets reproduced sometimes when I freshly launch the web app.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, except it's consistently upon the first refresh within the session. Cache emits a checking event and the cache state stays on checking until a subsequent refresh, when it always works. Have you figured this out or gotten any more clarity regarding this issue??

Comment: Hey @wildBillMunson, Since this feature is going to be deprecated by apple, the support hasn't come. you can do a workaround instead, have a listener on the checking event and may be after a settimeout of 3-4 seconds you can perform your further calls.

Comment: yes that is the hot-fix I came up with as well. Thanks!

Comment: I will add that as an answer for now, so that others can make use of it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this feature is going to be deprecated by apple, the support hasn't come. you can do a workaround instead, have a listener on the checking event and may be after a setTimeout of 3-4 seconds you can perform your further calls.

Will keep this thread posted once an update comes.